# 日本語係り受け解析器cabochaのインストールエラー

Tags: linux, 自然言語処理, cabocha

ubuntu14.04LTSに[cabocha](https://code.google.com/p/cabocha/)をインストールしようとすると、コンパイル・リンクの段階で以下の様なエラーが出力されました。

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: ディレクトリ `/home/UserName/cabocha-0.64' に入ります
Making all in src
make[2]: ディレクトリ `/home/UserName/cabocha-0.64/src' に入ります
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++  -O3 -Wno-deprecated -Wall   -o cabocha cabocha.o libcabocha.la -lcrfpp  
libtool: link: g++ -O3 -Wno-deprecated -Wall -o .libs/cabocha cabocha.o  ./.libs/libcabocha.so -lcrfpp
./.libs/libcabocha.so: undefined reference to `mecab_lattice_clear'
./.libs/libcabocha.so: undefined reference to `mecab_strerror'
./.libs/libcabocha.so: undefined reference to `mecab_lattice_get_bos_node'
./.libs/libcabocha.so: undefined reference to `mecab_lattice_new'
./.libs/libcabocha.so: undefined reference to `mecab_lattice_set_sentence2'
./.libs/libcabocha.so: undefined reference to `mecab_destroy'
./.libs/libcabocha.so: undefined reference to `mecab_lattice_add_request_type'
./.libs/libcabocha.so: undefined reference to `mecab_parse_lattice'
./.libs/libcabocha.so: undefined reference to `mecab_lattice_strerror'
./.libs/libcabocha.so: undefined reference to `mecab_dictionary_info'
./.libs/libcabocha.so: undefined reference to `mecab_new'
./.libs/libcabocha.so: undefined reference to `mecab_lattice_destroy'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [cabocha] エラー 1
make[2]: ディレクトリ `/home/UserName/cabocha-0.64/src' から出ます
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] エラー 1
make[1]: ディレクトリ `/home/UserName/cabocha-0.64' から出ます
make: *** [all] エラー 2
```

どうすればインストールできるのでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mecab 関連のライブラリがないためにエラーとなっています。Ubuntu 14.04 の場合、

```
# apt-get install libmecab2 libmecab-dev
```

としますと Mecabのライブラリとインクルードファイルなどがインストールされます。

上記を実行した後、Cabocha 側でもう一度 `configure` を実行してから `make` を実行して下さい。同じ環境でビルドしましたが、Cabocha の実行形式がビルドされた後、インデックスが生成される事を確認しました。

追記:

既に解決された様ですが、CRF++ ライブラリが /usr/local/lib にインストールされている場合、Cabocha 関連のコマンドを実行した際にダイナミックリンクができなくて(libcrfpp が見つからない)エラーになる場合があります。その場合は以下の様にして libcrfpp.so をインストールしたパスを Cabocha の実行形式に埋め込んで置くように設定すると良いかと思います。

```
$ LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib" ./configure
$ make
```

Comment: 上記コマンドを入力したらできました。。ありがとうございました。

Comment: しかし、係り受け解析ができません。なぜでしょうか？

Comment: configure のオプションである、"--with-charset" はどの様に指定しましたか？ 指定しないと EUC-JP になってしまいます。

Comment: utf-8で行ってはいました。
インストールで詰まっていた時に行った設定で、cabocharc関係でいらない設定をしていたため、正しくインストールできていなかったようです。usr/local/etc/cabocharcを削除してインストールしたら正しく動作しました。