# ubuntu16.04LTSにcabochaをインストールしようとすると、make時にエラー

Tags: ubuntu, cabocha

ubuntu16.04LTSにcabochaをインストールしようとすると、make時にエラーが出ました。

```sh
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/zip/cabocha-0.69'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/zip/cabocha-0.69/src'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/zip/cabocha-0.69/src'
Making all in model
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/zip/cabocha-0.69/model'
../src/cabocha-model-index -f UTF8 -t utf8 chunk.ipa.txt chunk.ipa.model
/home/ubuntu/zip/cabocha-0.69/src/.libs/lt-cabocha-model-index: error while loading shared libraries: libcrfpp.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Makefile:499: recipe for target 'chunk.ipa.model' failed
make[2]: *** [chunk.ipa.model] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/zip/cabocha-0.69/model'
Makefile:508: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/zip/cabocha-0.69'
Makefile:375: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

いろいろなサイトを見て、cabochaのいろんなバージョンを試したりしてるのですがうまくいきません。上に貼ってるエラーは、最新のcabocha-0.69をインストールしようとしたものです...

Comment: [日本語係り受け解析器cabochaのインストールエラー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/2846)

Answer (score 1):

CRF++ を適切にインストールしてください。

具体的なエラー内容が書かれているのはこの行です。

```
/home/ubuntu/zip/cabocha-0.69/src/.libs/lt-cabocha-model-index: error while loading shared libraries: libcrfpp.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

エラーメッセージを読むと「`libcrfpp` が見つからない」と言っています。[cabocha のホームページ](https://taku910.github.io/cabocha/)によると、Unix へ cabocha をインストールする前の準備として [CRF++](https://taku910.github.io/crfpp/) をインストールしなければいけません。`libcrfpp` が見えていないということは、これのインストールをしていない、または、インストールに失敗しているのだろうと思います。